# Flutter app not compiling after upgrading

Tags: flutter

[image: image of log]

output of flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

• No issues found!

After i did dart pub upgrade ...i got the following..

[image: output]

output of --stacktrace

[image: stack_trace_op]

Comment: if pub get doesn't work try uninstalling and reinstalling the app

Comment: i'm getting this error when i'm trying to install the app. Not able to build the app.

Comment: as the error message said, run with  `--stacktrace` option, then post new screenshots

Comment: have updated...@p2kr

Comment: How did you fix the issue, plz?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and I tried

```sh
flutter clean
```

and then

```
dart pub upgrade
```

for the Dependencies upgrade.

and then it started working you can just click on the Pub Upgrade in Android studio in `pubspec.yml` file of your projects.
Or you can remove the dependency which is creating issue after upgarde.

Comment: have updated the question with the output of  dart pub upgrade. The 5 dependencies that are showing compatible issues ....i'm not using those libraries in my project.

Comment: you can remove their version and write any instead of version and can try.

Comment: did'nt work...I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling flutter sdk.